# faraday builder use multixml to parse body

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, faraday

I want to setup faraday to use multi_xml and parse my responses body by default.

```
@connection = Faraday.new(base_url) {|builder| builder.response :xml, content_type: /xml/}
```

Leads to:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
from /Users/blanecordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@can/gems/faraday_middleware-0.9.1/lib/faraday_middleware/response_middleware.rb:59:in `response_type'
from /Users/blanecordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@can/gems/faraday_middleware-0.9.1/lib/faraday_middleware/response_middleware.rb:31:in `block in call'
from /Users/blanecordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@can/gems/faraday-0.9.0/lib/faraday/response.rb:57:in `on_complete'
from /Users/blanecordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@can/gems/faraday_middleware-0.9.1/lib/faraday_middleware/response_middleware.rb:30:in `call'
from /Users/blanecordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@can/gems/faraday-0.9.0/lib/faraday/rack_builder.rb:139:in `build_response'
from /Users/blanecordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@can/gems/faraday-0.9.0/lib/faraday/connection.rb:377:in `run_request'
from /Users/blanecordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@can/gems/faraday-0.9.0/lib/faraday/connection.rb:177:in `post'
```

Line 59 in gem:

```
 def response_type(env)
  type = env[:response_headers][CONTENT_TYPE].to_s
  type = type.split(';', 2).first if type.index(';')
  type
end
```

Comment: What if you used `content_type: /\bxml$/`. Also, can you `curl` that HTTP path and see indeed you are getting a response?

Comment: @cevaris I get the same response when using /\bxml$/ I get a response when I remove the builder block so its something to do with that

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the builder variable outside the block like this...

```
@connection = Faraday.new(base_url) do |builder| 
   builder.response :xml, content_type: /xml/
end
```

Here is an example that seems to work for me.

```
require 'faraday'
require 'faraday_middleware'
require 'pp'

base_url = 'http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml'
@connection = Faraday.new(base_url) do |builder| 
   builder.response :xml,  :content_type => /\bxml$/
end
pp @connection
```

Comment: line 59 in the gem is     def response_type(env)
      type = env[:response_headers][CONTENT_TYPE].to_s
      type = type.split(';', 2).first if type.index(';')
      type
    end

Comment: Just assuming, but are you using the gem `faraday_middleware`? If so, I just updated my answer using that.

Answer (score 0):

Encountered error is caused by the missing adapter declaration. You have to put it at the end of builder's block.

```
require 'faraday'
require 'faraday_middleware'

@connection = Faraday.new(base_url) do |builder|
  builder.response :xml, content_type: /\bxml$/
  builder.adapter Faraday.default_adapter
end
```

See: [faraday_middleware's wiki](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday_middleware/wiki#faraday_middleware-documentation)